# Regex: Preg_match - Specific search works in English but not in Hebrew

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Trying to match all quotation marks (") that are between:
Look-behind - 1 character of anything but `[אבג]` and 1 character of only `[אבג]`
Look-ahead - Any character `[א-ת]`.

As can be tested - https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html -

The following works in English:

```
/(?<=[^xyz]{1}[xyz]{1})"(?=[a-z])/i
```

But not in Hebrew:

```
/(?<=[^אבג]{1}[אבג]{1})"(?=[א-ת])/
```

Any help will be appreciated, 
Many thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use modifier `u` for unicode characters :

```
/(?<=[^אבג]{1}[אבג]{1})"(?=[א-ת])/u
```